# Angular2 how to do a url query string

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a search feature on my application which searches a list of products, which is all going okay however I want to redirect the user to another page say `www.site.com/search?keyword=perfume`

I can only make it `www.site.com/search/perfume` and `www.site.com/search;keyword=perfume`

Router navigate `this.router.navigate(['search', {keyword: searchVal}]);` doing this results as `www.site.com/search;keyword=perfume`

Routes

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent} 
];
```

Search function:

```
findproduct(searchTerm: HTMLInputElement): void {
var searchVal = searchTerm.value;
this.productService.searchproduct(searchVal)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.router.navigate(['search', {keyword: searchVal}]);
    console.log(data)
  });
```

}

How can I make my url to be `www.site.com/search?keyword=perfume`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `queryParams`:

```
this.router.navigate(['/search'], { queryParams: { keyword: searchVal } });
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I thought I had to put the param in []. This worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You should update your appRoutes as follow:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'search/:keyword', component: SearchComponent} 
];
```

Comment: This will output a parameter `/search/product` not a query string `/search?keyword=product`